# sidewaystable doesn't fit in a page

Tags: tables, rotating

How could we fit these tables into a page each?

**TABLE 1**

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c c} 
\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Agriculture} & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Industry}& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Services}\\
   \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8} \cline{10-12}
& Male & Female & \% of GDP && Male & Female & \% of GDP && Male & Female & \% of GDP \\
 \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8} \cline{10-12}
\textbf{Africa} &&&&&&&&&&&\\
Liberia\footnote{Data of 2010}&49.5&48.3&53.1&&13.5&4.8&4.8&&37&46.8&37.9\\
South Africa\footnote{Data of 2011}&5.5&3.5&2.5&&32.8&13.2&29.2&&58.3&68.4&68.3\\
\textbf{Asia}&&&&&&&&&&&\\
Cambodia$^b$&55&56.6&36.7&&16.3&17.5&23.5&&28.7&26&39.8\\
Indonesia$^b$&37&35&14.7&&24&15&47.2&&40&50&38.1\\
Malaysia$^a$&16&8.5&10.4&&31.3&21&40.3&&52.8&70.5&48.5\\
Sri Lanka$^a$&30.2&37.8&12.1&&23.9&24.8&29.4&&28.3&27.2&57.8\\
Philippines$^b$&41.3&22.5&12.8&&17.7&9.9&31.5&&41.1&67.6&55.7\\
Thailand$^b$&40.5&36.6&12.4&&22.9&18&41.2&&36.6&45.4&46.5\\
Bhutan$^b$&53.3&67.8&15.9&&9.8&8.5&43.9&&36.9&23.7&40.2\\
\textbf{Latin America}&&&&&&&&&&&\\
Colombia$^a$&26.1&5&7.1&&22.7&15.8&35&&51&79.1&57.9\\
Costa Rica$^a$&20.1&4.3&7.1&&24.9&11.4&26.2&&54.6&84.2&66.7\\
Honduras$^a$&49.9&11.9&12.5&&18.6&21.2&26.5&&31.3&66.7&60.9\\
Mexico$^a$&18.6&4&3.9&&30.1&17.8&34.7&&50.5&77.5&61.4\\
Nicaragua$^a$&44.2&15.2&18.6&&17.6&14.8&23.8&&38.1&69.8&57.6\\
\textbf{Developed Countries}&&&&&&&&&&&\\
United Kingdom$^b$&1.7&0.7&0.7&&29.1&7.5&21.6&&68.5&91.2&77.7\\
United States$^a$&2.3&0.8&1.2&&25.1&7.2&19.8&&71.7&91.9&79\\
  [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline \hline
\footnotesize Source: \cite{wb}, tabs. 2.3 (p.47), 4.2 (p.76)
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

**TABLE 2**

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c} 
\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
& \textbf{GNI} & \textbf{Life} & \textbf{Prevalence of} & \textbf{Health}  & \textbf{Access to} & \textbf{Access to}  \\
& \textbf{per capita} & \textbf{expectancy} & \textbf{under-nourishment} & \textbf{expenditure} & \textbf{improved} & \textbf{ improved}\\
&&&&& \textbf{water source} & \textbf{sanitation facilities}\\
& \textit{constant 2005 US \$ (2011)} & \textit{total (years)} & \textit{\% of population} & \textit{\$ (2011)} & \textit{\% of population (2010)} & \textit{\% of population}\\
\hline% inserts single horizontal line
\textbf{World} & 7519.76 & 70.54 & 12.76 & 951.58 & 88$^w$ & 63$^w$ \\ 
\textbf{Low Income} & 407.79 & 61.14 & 28.15 & 31.17 & 65 & 37 \\ 
\textbf{Middle Income} & 2589.99 & 69.92 & 12.65 & 245.71 & 90 & 59 \\ 
\textbf{High Income} & 30638.66 & 78.88 & 5 & 4607.2 & 100 & 100 \\ 
 [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Please always post complete (small) documents not fragments. Whether it fits on a page depends on the page size and fonts that you haven't shown, and in any case it just helps people to test their answers.

Comment: Btw: using bold face is ugly, not just in tables. Have a look at [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to read something about nice looking tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To narrow the tables you should drop empty columns and maybe reorganize them a bit. And there are several other points to improve them.

- The »[booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)« package for a better look especially regarding the horizontal rules.
- The »[siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)« package for digit alignment in the respective columns.
- The »[threeparttable](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable)« package for table notes instead of footnotes.

Another prerequisite is an appropriate type area by e.g. »[geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)« to make the tables fit the page. Alternatively you can decrease the font size inside the `table` environment (but *before* `tabular`). The corresponding modifications for the first table could look like this. I'm sure you will be able to apply that to the second one.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}  % drop `showframe` option in actual document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Table caption}\label{tab:dummy}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabular}{
        l
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
      } \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Agriculture}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Industry}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Services} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
        & {Male} & {Female} & {\% of GDP}
        & {Male} & {Female} & {\% of GDP}
        & {Male} & {Female} & {\% of GDP} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
        \textbf{Africa}              &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
        Liberia\tnote{a}             & 49.5 & 48.3 & 53.1 & 13.5 &  4.8 &  4.8 & 37   & 46.8 & 37.9 \\
        South Africa\tnote{b}        &  5.5 &  3.5 &  2.5 & 32.8 & 13.2 & 29.2 & 58.3 & 68.4 & 68.3 \\ \addlinespace
        \textbf{Asia}                &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
        Cambodia\tnote{b}            & 55   & 56.6 & 36.7 & 16.3 & 17.5 & 23.5 & 28.7 & 26   & 39.8 \\
        Indonesia\tnote{b}           & 37   & 35   & 14.7 & 24   & 15   & 47.2 & 40   & 50   & 38.1 \\
        Malaysia\tnote{a}            & 16   &  8.5 & 10.4 & 31.3 & 21   & 40.3 & 52.8 & 70.5 & 48.5 \\
        Sri Lanka\tnote{a}           & 30.2 & 37.8 & 12.1 & 23.9 & 24.8 & 29.4 & 28.3 & 27.2 & 57.8 \\
        Philippines\tnote{b}         & 41.3 & 22.5 & 12.8 & 17.7 &  9.9 & 31.5 & 41.1 & 67.6 & 55.7 \\
        Thailand\tnote{b}            & 40.5 & 36.6 & 12.4 & 22.9 & 18   & 41.2 & 36.6 & 45.4 & 46.5 \\
        Bhutan\tnote{b}              & 53.3 & 67.8 & 15.9 &  9.8 &  8.5 & 43.9 & 36.9 & 23.7 & 40.2 \\ \addlinespace
        \textbf{Latin America}       &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
        Colombia\tnote{a}            & 26.1 &  5   &  7.1 & 22.7 & 15.8 & 35   & 51   & 79.1 & 57.9 \\
        Costa Rica\tnote{a}          & 20.1 &  4.3 &  7.1 & 24.9 & 11.4 & 26.2 & 54.6 & 84.2 & 66.7 \\
        Honduras\tnote{a}            & 49.9 & 11.9 & 12.5 & 18.6 & 21.2 & 26.5 & 31.3 & 66.7 & 60.9 \\
        Mexico\tnote{a}              & 18.6 &  4   &  3.9 & 30.1 & 17.8 & 34.7 & 50.5 & 77.5 & 61.4 \\
        Nicaragua\tnote{a}           & 44.2 & 15.2 & 18.6 & 17.6 & 14.8 & 23.8 & 38.1 & 69.8 & 57.6 \\ \addlinespace
        \textbf{Developed Countries} &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
        United Kingdom\tnote{b}      &  1.7 &  0.7 &  0.7 & 29.1 &  7.5 & 21.6 & 68.5 & 91.2 & 77.7 \\
        United States\tnote{a}       &  2.3 &  0.8 &  1.2 & 25.1 &  7.2 & 19.8 & 71.7 & 91.9 & 79   \\ \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] Data of 2010
        \item[b] Data of 2011
        \item Source: \cite{wb}, tabs. 2.3 (p.47), 4.2 (p.76)
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't trim the `\cmidrule`s one the right if they end with the final column: To me, it looks wrong if the final `\cmidrule` doesn't terminate in the same position as do `\toprule` and `midrule`.

Comment: @Mico: In some things there is a personal taste. I did it this way due to symmetry reasons.

Comment: What about the second table which doesn't fit in the page at all?

Comment: @giannis: My answer was actually intended as a starting point and as an example to be applied to the second table. As I already mentioned you should reorganize that table. That concerns above all the bold text in the head. Try to get narrower columns and don't typeset bold faced.